# Apache - Disabled SNI

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server, ssl, stunnel

I'm having a bit of trouble with my webserver. Whenever I connect to Apache using SSL, I get a 400 Bad Request. I've looked in Apache's error log, and I see:

```
 [ssl:error] [pid 30065] AH02032: Hostname 127.0.0.1 provided via SNI and hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx provided via HTTP are different
```

The reason for this is likely my usage of stunnel + sslh, which is:

```
stunnel:443 -> sslh -> stunnel:444 -> apache(ssl):4431
```

I use this because my university blocks all non-SSL traffic on port 443 and uses DPI on other ports, and I require both SSH and HTTPS. I was wondering if there was a way to stop Apache from required the two to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [Can't turn off SNI on apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/421250/cant-turn-off-sni-on-apache), where [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/a/421253/238995) mentioned it's not possible to disable and [eckes](https://serverfault.com/a/479383/238995) suggested that if you can force HTTP/1.0 you should bypass the SNI problem (either client or server side I guess).

> The reason for this is likely my usage of stunnel + sslh,
>
> > stunnel:443 -> sslh -> stunnel:444 -> apache(ssl):4431

stunnel ([manpage](http://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html)) can send SNI headers. So you can probaly fix your problem at that level, but that's worth another question.